# documentation for learning SciLab?

Tags: documentation, graphing, scilab

I'd like to use [SciLab](http://www.scilab.org/) as an alternative for the 90% of things I need to do that don't require MATLAB's proprietary functionality (and for which we have a limited # of expensive concurrent licenses at my company).

Is there an introductory manual or primer? Google for "scilab manual" shows the 'manual' [as a flat list of functions](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/) that is of little help for someone new to the program.

I guess I'm spoiled by Mathworks's [documentation on MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/), notably the user guides, and was hoping there might be something similar.

Comment: why the MATLAB tag if it is not related to it?

Comment: good point -- I'm coming at this as a fluent MATLAB user, so that was my intent, but this question could be useful for anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scilab website has [an official tutorial on Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/content/download/1754/19024/file/introscilab.pdf) that is pretty good.

I maintain a list of unofficial tutorials [here](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/student/~sengupta/scilab/).

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea how I missed that, since it's right up there on the tutorials page http://www.scilab.org/support/documentation/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the Equalis [website](http://www.equalis.com) for Scilab help forums, user groups and documentation.